# Подсчитать колличество повторяющихся элементов в массиве, PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как селать следующее: есть массив вида:

```
 array([6] => Planned
     [7] => Held
     [8] => Held
     [9] => Planned
     [10] => str
     [11] => Planned
     [12] => str
     [13] => Planned
     [14] => wer
     [15] => Held
)
```

Это часть массива вообще он довольно большой (примерно 2000-чи элементов), нужно подсчитать сколько в нём повторений элементов, т.е. Planned и т.д. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать, это. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Извиняюсь, что сразу не заметил вот этого, а я городил всякую хрень с циклами

```
 print_r(array_count_values($status));
```

Comment: я тоже раньше писал свои велосипеды, пока не нашел эту функцию))